# Bootstrap tab content slideDown/slideUp not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

i'm using bootstrap alpha tab , actually my code is big so can't really paste here all those but i'm giving few example code.
I want the tab-content on click slideUp /SlideDown  .But it's not happening it just doing normal tab option,I want slideDown the tab-content on click the tab menu and slideUp when click that menu again.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.nav-link.active', function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $('.tab-pane[id="' + href + '"]').removeClass('active');
  $('.tab-content').slideDown(600);
});
```

```css
.tab-pane {
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.tab-content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="nav" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="home" role="tabpanel">Good</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">Best</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">Poor</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">Ugly</div>
</div>
```

Please help me.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/otpq2c5j/)

Answer (score 0):

Running your demo and looking at the Console's logs.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slideDown is not a function
>
> at HTMLAnchorElement. ((index):76)
>
> at HTMLDocument.dispatch (VM106 jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
>
> at HTMLDocument.q.handle (VM106 jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)

Since there's an error with the SlideDown function, it will has no effect.
It seems that the jQuery library file you're including doesn't have that function.

**Step 1: jquery.slim**

You're including the slim version of jQuery.
According to the source:

> Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the ajax and
>   effects modules, we’re releasing a “slim” version that **excludes** these
>   modules. All in all, it excludes ajax, effects, and currently
>   deprecated code.

So, for instance, slideDown isn't available in this version.
You should use the regular version (minified if you wish, but not the slim one).

https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: so what should i have to do now

Comment: it's the jquery library you're using, i'm checking why.

Comment: yeah I also can see that but can't really figure it out why :(

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: is it working correctly? because i've also updated but vain

Comment: Ok, first - make sure you include jQuery before bootstrap.js. Second, What's the goal of your script? According to the code, I believe you're looking for slideUp, not slideDown. http://jsfiddle.net/otpq2c5j/25/

Comment: look it's doing good now,But what i want is when i click ion the menu it should slide down and when click that menu again it should slideUp

Comment: Then you should modify your script to adjust that. Add a click event handler for the element without the "active" class (=show the tab with slideDown), and with the current event handler use the slideUp function.

Comment: i've asked that in question too,Please if you can do this

Comment: I will help but I won't write your code for you, it's not how this community works.

Comment: I've written all the codes,just show me one time that what it should be to slideup and slidedown

Answer (score 0):

Please check your included jQuery version, slideDown() is undefined. I would try to include another, for example from google library: [jQuery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery)

And then:slideDown() can´t work with visible elements. So you have to change your code like that:

```
$(document).on('click','.nav-link.active', function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
     $(this).removeClass('active');
     $('.tab-pane[id="'+ href +'"]').removeClass('active'); 
     $('.tab-content').hide().slideDown(600); 
});
```

... or `display: none` with css to hide your element before make it visible with the slideDown function.